# Run internal commands in script stdin!

Tags: command-line, 18.04, bash, scripts, process

I have this process:

```
$ bash start.sh
```

I run this command:

```
$ pidof bash
```

And receive this:

```
9427
```

I want to run commands in the script stdin(the script has its own commands)
I want to run command "`give 1 shotgun to player`"
I tried this:

```
$ give 1 shotgun to player > /proc/9427/fd/0
```

But I got this:

```
-bash: give: command not found
```

After, I tried this:

```
$ echo "give 1 shotgun to player" > /proc/9427/fd/0
```

But the message "`give 1 shotgun to player`" was written in the process, but script's command wasn't activated!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot intercept the already existing stdin of a process, at least not the way you are trying. See [Writing to stdin of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process) for details.

There are two basic options to control a process from another using stdin but they must be specified when launching the process.

## Input from a file (script)

If you can prepare the whole input before launching the process to be controlled, create a file and use it as the stdin of the controlled process. Example:

```
$ cat commands
give 1 shotgun to player
shoot

$ ./start.sh < commands
```

## Input from a process

If you use another program to issue commands that control your process, connect them both using the pipe symbol (`|`). The following example shows how to simply control *when* to issue the commands.

```
$ cat controller.sh
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
echo "give 1 shotgun to player"
sleep 2
echo "shoot"

$ ./controller.sh | ./start.sh
```

This way you can also use `echo` as you tried to simulate the script option without using any script file:

```
$ echo "give 1 shotgun to player\nshoot" | ./start.sh
```

Comment: The process is already started!

Comment: this starts again start.sh script

Comment: Yes, I’ve presented commands that launch a process with the specified input. I don’t know how to intercept stdin of a process, you have to wait for another answerer.

Answer (score 2):

The [Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385771/writing-to-stdin-of-a-process) Melebius linked to actually provides a solution that let's you write to `stdin` of another process:

Using `mkfifo` you can create a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). You can then redirect `stdin` of your process to the named pipe and write to it from another process:

```
$ mkfifo myfifo.pipe
$ ./start.sh < myfifo.pipe
```

... and from another terminal:

```
$ echo "give 1 shotgun to player" > myfifo.pipe
```

Comment: @Melebius no, you have to redirect `stdin` when starting the program. But you don't have to specify what is being written to it in advance. I guess the OP is starting a game(server). He can then  "give 1 shotgun to player" whenever he wants.

Comment: Yes you right, but game server won't start!

Comment: @Bogdan does it start when you run `./start.sh`? Could you provide a link to the script?